# Ireport counter initial expression

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I created a counter in ireport design 5.6.0, however the first number is null, then 2 3 4 ...
It's not showing 1. How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: You can set the *Initial Value*

Answer (score 0):

Report variables are not like variables in procedural programming languages.

You don't need to do $V{Counter}++, the variable expression specifies what is to be counted (like COUNT(something) is SQL).  If you want a simple counter you can use a constant expression like 1 or "a string".